# Get info of exposed models in Tensorflow Serving

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Once I have a TF server serving multiple models, is there a way to query such server to know which models are served?

Would it be possible then to have information about each of such models, like name, interface and, even more important, what versions of a model are present on the server and could potentially be served?

Answer (score 9):

It is really hard to find some info about this, but there is possibility to get some model metadata.

```py
request = get_model_metadata_pb2.GetModelMetadataRequest()
request.model_spec.name = 'your_model_name'
request.metadata_field.append("signature_def")
response = stub.GetModelMetadata(request, 10)
    
print(response.model_spec.version.value)
print(response.metadata['signature_def'])
```

Hope it helps.

### Update

Is is possible get these information from REST API. Just get

```
http://{serving_url}:8501/v1/models/{your_model_name}/metadata
```

Result is json, where you can easily find model specification and signature definition.

Comment: Any idea on how to decode the bytes contained in response.metadata['signature_def'] here?

Comment: This answer is also useful for cases where a developer see the following error: GetModelMetadataRequest must specify at least one metadata_field

Comment: Is it possible to get a list of all models that are served in Tensorflow serving?

Answer (score 0):

To continue the decoding process, either follow Tyler's approach and convert the message to JSON, or more natively Unpack into a SignatureDefMap and take it from there

```
signature_def_map = get_model_metadata_pb2.SignatureDefMap()
response.metadata['signature_def'].Unpack(signature_def_map)
print(signature_def_map.signature_def.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

To request data using REST API, for additional data of the particular model that is served, you can issue (via curl, Postman, etc.):

```
GET http://host:port/v1/models/${MODEL_NAME}
GET http://host:port/v1/models/${MODEL_NAME}/metadata
```

For more information, please check https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the code neither http not grpc support listing all deployed models:

https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/tree/master/tensorflow_serving/model_servers